# SQL Store View Snapshots and Changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I use a SELECT query in SQL, it is my understanding that it is generating a kind of temporary view from the underlying tables. I am in need of the ability to store changes to this view, almost like storing INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements that would be applied to this temporary view. The goal is to store all the information for a view at preset timestamps, these would be the snapshots. Then to store the timestamped changes to the view, and be able to efficiently apply these changes to the most recent snapshot so that I can use the view as it was at a given time.

Any way of doing what I need?

Thanks

Comment: The technical name for this is "materialized views".  SQL Server implements them using indexed views.  Here is a place to start:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Temporal Tables, SQL Server added support in SS2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: @dnoeth The Temporal Tables are almost what I need, except they seem to be over-managed by the system for my needs. I need to be able to specify the timestamps for the changes made, rather than have the system react to a change being made. I need to schedule these changes to define what the view will look like in the future and specify what it looked like in the past.

Comment: @dnoeth The querying aspect of the Temporal Tables, however, is spot-on for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> ...my understanding that it is generating a kind of temporary view from the underlying tables...

No.

The database engine produces a "result set" from the underlying tables in the way it best sees fit.

If the query can be "pipelined" then the engine usually produces one row at a time and delivers (for efficiency) them in batches.

It the query cannot be pipelined, then it may produce internal materialized result set(s) that could cover tables entirely or partially.

Bottom line, you don't really have control on the details. SQL is by definition a "declarative" language, not an "imperative" one. You say what you need, then the database engine figures out (for good or bad) the best way of getting it.

If you really want to look under the hood I recommend you get the "execution plan" of the query. That tells you all the tricks the engine is performing to get what you asked.